# How to grill potatoes?

Tags: grilling, potatoes, barbecue

I'm having a barbecue and I'm cooking steaks and asparagus. I still have some uncooked potatoes left in the pantry. Is it possible to grill a potato?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I've removed the recipe request from your question since that is not an appropriate question to have answered here.

Comment: A baking sheet with holes in the bottom where smoke can come through works great for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a "Grill Wok" that I received as a gift that looks like this:

[image]

It is great for grilling potatoes.

1. Peel and cube to about 1" pieces.
2. Par boiling or microwaving works equally well for blanching the
   cubes.
3. Toss in a large bowl with olive oil and melted butter
4. Add seasoning: salt, pepper, chili powder, oregano, etc. (to taste)
5. Allow Grill Wok to preheat on the grill, when hot add potatoes.
6. Cook till golden brown

---

*(I believe mine was obtained at Bass Pro Shop, but they are available elsewhere)*

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  I par-boil them first for 15 mins, then toss in oil and seasoning, thread on skewers and barbecue for 7-8 mins, turning often.  Lovely.

Comment: How should the potato be cut before skewering?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to go about grilling potatoes. One simple approach that I've been using lately is to clean up the potatoes; cut them into half-inch disks; toss with oil, salt, and pepper; and grill over medium-high heat for until browned on the first side. Flip and brown the other side.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to cook potatoes on the grill (but isn't grilling) ...

- Cube up the potatoes, drizzle with oil, salt, and whatever other seasonings you like
- Lay out a large piece of heavy duty aluminum foil.
- Place the potatoes on one side of the foil, fold it closed, and crimp the edges shut.
- Toss on the grill while you're pre-heating it, then move it to a cooler location while you're cooking everything else.  (my grill has a top shelf, so I put it up there).

Exact cooking time depends on how hot of a place you set it on the grill ... anywhere from 30 to 60 minutes is typical.  You'll want to turn the whole thing over at least once ... you may need to use a wide spatula to life it safely, depending on how large your packet is.  You'll get some char, but it's really more a steam than a grill.

If you want them to dry out some, you can break open the top of the packet after about 30 minutes, and let some of the steam escape, but this also makes it more difficult to remove from the grill.

...

You can also just do baked potatoes on the grill, if you have time ... I just start the grill early, on medium (might be low for other grills), and add whole potatoes that have been scrubbed, rubbed in oil, and salted, and cook over low or indirect heat for about an hour.